# xampp not recognizing the paths

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I just installed Xampp portable on a flash drive as my test environment and all services works fine. I copied my website folder from my webserver to the htdocs folder of the xampp and now xampp doesn't recognize the paths to the include_once's in the webpages and it says: Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkmobile() in F:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\includes\html_head.php on line 15

ie, there is a include_once checkmobile.php above the line 15 but the xampp doesn't recognize the path! BTW, this works from my webserver...

I am trying to keep the paths the same so when I transfer the website files back to the production server, I don't have to change all the paths again...

Any solution to this?
Am I doing something wrong or have to modify some config files in xampp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue as long as you aren't hard coding the path. What is your directory structure (just an outline is fine) and can you give us a snipped of the code with the include request in it?

Comment: Now I realizzed that it reads the paths but doesn't recognize php and reads it as html! or I think it's doing this... ie, I have this as include_once for mysql connection: <?
 $user = 'test';
 $pswd = 'test';
 $db = 'main';
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pswd);
 mysql_select_db($db, $connect);
 if ($connect) {
  echo '<br><br>Connected<br><br>';
 } else {
  echo '<br><br>Not Connected<br><br>';
 }
?> and this is coming back:

Comment: Thank you, this <?php did the trick! But now it doesn't recognize my username and password for this database.

Comment: Make sure you have set up the mySQL database through xampp if you are using the localhost database. The default username and password if I remember correctly for the root user is just "root"@"localhost" with no password.

Comment: Thank you again, I will check that!